Почему разные цены по купонам для авторизованных и не авторизованных?
Есть код:
$coupon = array("CUPON");

$externalUserIdArray = ['3','4','8','2'];
$prices = CCatalogProduct::GetOptimalPrice(1099647, 1, $externalUserIdArray, 'N', '', 's1', $coupon);

echo "<h3> СО СКИДКОЙ ".$prices['DISCOUNT_PRICE']."</h3>";


print_r($prices);

Почему этот код дает разный рузультат для авторизованных и не авторизованных пользователей?
Доступ к ценам есть у всех

Не зная, что делает и как CCatalogProduct::GetOptimalPrice, не возможно сказать, почему разные данные.

он дает минимально возможную цену исходя из группы пользователя, id товара, промокода

Возможно в коде заложена логика для авторизованных пользователей.

Возможно, в правилах скидок есть скидки для сделавших покупки на определённую сумму. Или ещё какие-нибудь условия, которые работают только на авторизованных.
